# ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index | calculating differences between dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset/pandas df with ~50 columns - columns are a mix of character, numeric, and dates.  5 of the columns are dates, labeled Meeting1-Meeting5, and I'm trying to calculate the days between meeting dates.

My df looks generally like this:

```
ID_number   Meeting1    Meeting2    Meeting3    Meeting4    Meeting5    Comments    …
123456789   2014-09-17  2015-04-22  2015-05-30   NaN         NaN         text text   …
987654321   2015-09-22  NaN         2016-02-20   NaN         NaN         text text   …
456789123   2016-10-22  2017-05-29  NaN          NaN         NaN         text text   …
```

In SQL I would typically use `SELECT DATEDIFF(dd,Meeting1,Meeting2) AS diff_mt1_mt2`
In Python I've tried using

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

df['diff_mt1_mt2'] = (df['Meeting2']-df['Meeting1'])
```

But get a ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index (full error below)

Is there an easier/better way to do this in Python?

Full error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-055085bc04d7> in <module>()
      3 from datetime import date
      4 
----> 5 df['diff_mt1_mt2'] = (df['Meeting2']-df['Meeting1']),

C:\Users\lmgagne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   2427         else:
   2428             # set column
-> 2429             self._set_item(key, value)
   2430 
   2431     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

C:\Users\lmgagne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   2493 
   2494         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 2495         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   2496         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   2497 

C:\Users\lmgagne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   2664 
   2665             # turn me into an ndarray
-> 2666             value = _sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
   2667             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):
   2668                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:

C:\Users\lmgagne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _sanitize_index(data, index, copy)
   2877 
   2878     if len(data) != len(index):
-> 2879         raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')
   2880 
   2881     if isinstance(data, PeriodIndex):

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

I'm using:

Python version 3.6.1 and Pandas version 0.20.1

Comment: Can you add data sample? Because it should work.

Comment: @jezrael added some data

Answer (score 0):

I think you need convert `Meeting` columns to `datetime`s first by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert non datetime to `NaT` (missing value for datetime):

```
#filter columns
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Meeting')]
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce'))

df['diff_mt1_mt2'] = (df['Meeting2']-df['Meeting1'])
```

Comment: Added this code, but it's still generating the same error

Comment: Very hard to answer without data. But maybe use old version of pandas.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d1 = pd.to_datetime(['2014-09-17','2015-04-22','2015-05-30',np.NaN,np.NaN])
d2= pd.to_datetime(['2015-09-22',np.NaN,'2016-02-20',np.NaN,np.NaN])
d3= pd.to_datetime(['2016-10-22','2017-05-29',np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN])
data=[d1,d2,d3]
index_serie = np.array((123456789,987654321,456789123))

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,index=index_serie,columns=['Meeting 1','Meeting 2','Meeting 3','Meeting 4','Meeting 5'])
df.index.name = 'ID_number'
df['diff_mt1_mt2'] = (df['Meeting 2']-df['Meeting 1'])
```

It works fine for me with the latest version of Python and Pandas.